# Counting in chars using list in python

Tags: python

i wanna make a program to count using characters from list.

This is what i have tried:

```
chars = """abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]{}'\"|;:,./<>?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹ`~"""
```

I don't know what to do next.

I want the program do this:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Etc...

Comment: sample input, expected output pls

Comment: `for i in chars: print(i)` ?

Comment: it is unclear what you want

Comment: There will no sample input, and i wanna go.

Comment: after 111 symbols it will go like this:

Comment: aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, af

Comment: `print(*chars, sep="\n")`?

Comment: No, read my last messages

Comment: @PiotrJakóbczak, Explain what you want in your question, not in the comments. Explain clearly, what do you mean by count? How should the input be? What should the output  be? I see you are new, so also take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

#### Single chars

---

Try with this:

```
for i in chars:
    print(i)
```

This is a simple `foreach loop` in which `i` is an element of `chars`.

You can also use the `print()` built-in function like this:

```
print(*chars, sep='\n')
```

This will print all the characters separated by `'\n'` which is an endline, like `endl` in `C++`.

#### If the loop ends?

---

As I read in the comments, you need to print `-` after the chars ended.
This should work:

```
for i in chars:
    print(i)
while True:
    print('-')
```

If you want to print the chars another time instead, you can try this:

```
while True:
    for i in chars:
        print(i)
```

#### aa, ab, ac

---

If you want they to print like this, you can try something like this:

```
for i in chars:
    print(i)
for i in range(len(chars)-1):
    print(chars[i] + chars[i+1])
```

This is a simple `for loop`, which has `i` as a counter, which works while `i < len(chars)-1`.
Then, when the loop stops, you can add something like this...

```
for i in range(len(chars)-2):
    print(chars[i] + chars[i+1] + chars[i+2])
```

...and so on.

Comment: I wanna go after 111 symbols written like this: aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,ag

Comment: @PiotrJakóbczak, ok, I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: It must go like this: a,b,c,d,e,f,g [...] aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,ag,ah [...] ba,bb,bc,bd

Comment: Check my code, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Because it goes on forever, what you need is a generator instead of an ordinary loop.

```py
from itertools import product


def generate(letters, start = 1):
    for i in product(letters, repeat=start):
        yield "".join(i)

    yield from generate(letters=letters, start=start + 1)
```

---

### Results

Let's print out the first 20 results.

```py
>>> g = generate("abcdef")
...
... for _ in range(20):
...    print(next(g), end=" ")

a b c d e f aa ab ac ad ae af ba bb bc bd be bf ca cb
```

You can replace `"abcdef"` with whatever string you want. For example, your preferred string.

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]{}'\"|;:,./<>?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZąćęłńóśżźĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŻŹ`~"
```

Comment: This is the right answer, +1, it should also be the accepted one.